# Problems rotating arrow labels

Tags: xy-pic, rotating

[`Xypic`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/) offers many placement and formatting options for labels, including rotation.

However, I can't get this last feature to work correctly.

I have two problems with this:

- with some inclinations the label won't be correctly shifted sideway (see the downleft arrow below)
- with some inclinations the label won't be correctly placed in the length of the arrow (see the left arrow below)

[image: Problem]

The normal aspect of the arrow being :

[image: How the arrow should look like]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\newcommand{\bijar}[1][]{%
    \ar[#1]
    \ar@<0.7ex>@{}[#1]|-*[@]{\sim}} 
          % Arrow for a
          % bijective mapping

\begin{document}

\[\xymatrix{
&&&& \\ 
&&&& \\
&& {\bullet}
  \bijar[rr]
  \bijar[uurr]
  \bijar[uu]
  \bijar[uull]
  \bijar[ll]
  \bijar[ddll]
  \bijar[dd]
  \bijar[ddrr]
&& \\
&&&& \\
&&&&
}\]

\end{document}
```

Some comments about the code: I draw this arrow in 2 arrows, one being only the arrow and the second one being an empty arrow, shifted by the desired dimension, and actually supporting the label. The reason I use that instead of regular labels is that it allows me to specify the distance between the label and the arrow. 
Also, I don't think it can be the problem. After all, sideway-shifted arrows are exactly in front of their normal position, they aren't shifted backward or forward.

I'm using `xy-pic 3.8.6` with `pdflatex`.

Edit : After reading this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/how-do-i-make-the-arrow-using-xymatrix), I came up with the following definition of the macro:

```
\newcommand{\bijar}[1][]{%
  \ar[#1]
  \ar@<0.7ex>@{}[#1]|-*@{~}} 
     % Arrow for a
     % bijective mapping
```

It indeed solves both of the above problems, but as you can see on the picture below, there is another problem appearing on "standard" directions :

[image: Problem2]

The other problem is that it works for this because `\sim` can be imitated by sloped arrow body, but for other arrows like open or closed immersions, this hack wouldn't work.

Comment: The curious thing is that I get the correct result with Xy-pic v. 3.8.5; I'll try later with the more recent version.

Comment: I can confirm that it's a bug introduced in v. 3.8.6

Comment: The version history mentions only a bug fix for color support in xypdf at 3.8.6... I guess I could downgrade without breaking any of my diagrams, but honestly, that's much of a hassle. Maybe it is an intentional change that has been made and that requires the user to change the syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After playing a while with the misc. parameters, I found out that the following code works :

```
\newcommand{\bijar}[1][]{%
 \ar[#1]
 \ar@<0.7ex>@{}[#1]|-*=0[@]{\sim}} 
      % Arrow for a
      % bijective mapping
```

It seems the placement is a problem with the rotating functions, which are acting on the whole object (including its frame). Resizing it to zero fixes the issue.