# Tikz'spicture: problems positioning shapes inside nodes and arrow's tips in the middle of the line

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw the picture above with tikz's code, and i would know the better way for placing the "zig-zag" lines. Also I would like to put the arrow's tip in the middle of the connection line. Someone could help me? Thanks.

[image]

---

This is a diffrent picture but whith the same problems:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,
intersections,
shapes.geometric,
decorations.pathmorphing,
decorations.pathreplacing,
decorations.shapes,
decorations.markings,
patterns,
calc,
fit,
arrows,
backgrounds,
matrix}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]

\tikzset{deco/.style={decoration={
            markings, 
            mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{>} }
            },
        postaction={decorate}},
   trape/.style={trapezium,draw,shape border rotate=90,minimum width=2cm},
   box/.style={rectangle,draw,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2.5cm},
   cerchi/.style={circle,draw,minimum size=1cm}
}

\matrix [row sep={1.5cm}] {
    &[2cm]  \node [box] (genera) {}; &[2cm]     &[1cm] \\
\node [cerchi] (pompa) {}; &     & \node [trape] (turbina) {};  & \node [cerchi] (ultiliz) {}; \\
 & \node [cerchi] (condensa) {};  & & \\ 
};

\begin{scope}[>=triangle 60]  
\draw [deco=0.6]  (genera) -|  node[pos=0.6]{2} (turbina.top right corner);
\draw [deco=0.6]  (turbina.bottom left corner) |-   node[above=1mm,pos=0.71]{3} (condensa);
\draw [deco=0.4]  (condensa) -|  node[above=1mm,pos=0.31]{4} (pompa);
\draw [deco=0.6]  (pompa) |-   node[below=1mm,pos=0.63]{1} (genera); 
\end{scope}

\draw [->,>=latex,very thick, shorten >=4 pt,shorten <=4pt] (pompa.south)--(pompa.north);

\node [coordinate] (B) at ($ (condensa.center)!.6!(condensa.west) $) {};
\node [coordinate] (C) at ($ (condensa.center)!.6!(condensa.east) $) {}; 
\node [coordinate] (A) at ($ (B)+(0,-1.5cm)$) {}; 
\node [coordinate] (D) at ($ (C)+(0,-1.5cm)$) {}; 
\draw (A)--(B); \draw[decorate,decoration={zigzag,amplitude=3pt,segment length=8pt}] (B)--(C); \draw (C)--(D); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's perhaps a good idea to define your two circuit symbols as new symbols with the tikz circuit library (see tikz manual). What do you mean exactly by "the better way"?

Comment: I could define shape using absolute coordinate and drawing lines trough that nodes...but I tkink that there is a better way to do that. I'will try to define new symbols with circuit library.

Comment: Please post a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that shows what you have done so far. For drawing lines in the middle of a line, have a look at [this queastion](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3161/tikz-how-to-draw-an-arrow-in-the-middle-of-the-line)

Comment: @student: Tags are based on the question, not on solutions.

Comment: @Caramdir I interpreted Angelo's comment "I'will try to define new symbols with circuit library." that he wants to use tikz-circuit library for this. Because of this I added the tag.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very simple construction of the circled resistor:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=west,shape=var resistor IEC,minimum width=1cm,draw,outer sep=0] (heater){};
\node[draw,circle,minimum size=3cm] (heater frame) at (heater.center) {};
\draw (-0.5cm,-2cm) |- (heater.west) (heater.east) -| (1.5cm,-2cm);
\draw[-latex,ultra thick,red] (heater frame.west) -- ++(-2cm,0);
\draw[latex-,ultra thick,blue] (heater frame.east) -- ++(2cm,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you combine this with [the answer regarding the arrows with nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54733/3235) then you get the essential parts to create the figure.