# Tikz: drawing a zig zag line inside a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw a zig-zag line inside a circle without using decorations. The size and positioning of the line should be relative to the size of the circle.
I used this code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw,circle,minimum size=1cm] (C) at (0,0){};

\draw    ($($ (C.west)!.1!(C.east) $)-(0,30pt)$)  --($ (C.west)!.1!(C.east) $)
       --($ (C.west)!.25!(C.east) $)              --($($ (C.west)!.3!(C.east) $)+(0,3pt)$)
       --($($ (C.west)!.4!(C.east) $)-(0,3pt)$)   --($($ (C.west)!.5!(C.east) $)+(0,3pt)$)
       --($($ (C.west)!.6!(C.east) $)-(0,3pt)$)   --($($ (C.west)!.7!(C.east) $)+(0,3pt)$)
       --($ (C.west)!.75!(C.east) $)              --($ (C.west)!.9!(C.east) $)
       --($($ (C.west)!.9!(C.east) $)-(0,30pt)$);
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

to get this:

[image]

The problem is that if I want to resize the circle, the vertical lines gets too short (or too long) and I have to fix the "vertical coordinate" manually.

[image]

It is possible to anchor the vertical coordinate relative to the node's shape??

Comment: Why does it need to be without decorations?

Comment: I thought this issue was resolved [in one of your previous questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54477/tikzspicture-problems-positioning-shapes-inside-nodes-and-arrows-tips-in-the/54736#54736). What is your real concern about this picture that has been the subject of 5 questions already?  :) Note that, resistor shape must comply with some standards.

Comment: @percusse and jake: in previous questions I used the decoration library but I couldn't fit the shape of the zig-zag lines to my needs. Also the shape I need it's not really a zig zag line.

Comment: @jake: thank you...the solution was very easy ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of defining the "legs" as `(0,-30pt)` (which, of course, doesn't scale), you can use `($(C.north)-(C.south)$)`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw,circle,minimum size=1.2cm] (C) at (0,0){};

\draw    ($($ (C.west)!.1!(C.east) $)-($(C.north)-(C.south)$)$)--($ (C.west)!.1!(C.east) $)
       --($ (C.west)!.25!(C.east) $)--($($ (C.west)!.3!(C.east) $)+(0,3pt)$)
       --($($ (C.west)!.4!(C.east) $)-(0,3pt)$)--($($ (C.west)!.5!(C.east) $)+(0,3pt)$)
       --($($ (C.west)!.6!(C.east) $)-(0,3pt)$)--($($ (C.west)!.7!(C.east) $)+(0,3pt)$)
       --($ (C.west)!.75!(C.east) $)--($ (C.west)!.9!(C.east) $)
       --($($ (C.west)!.9!(C.east) $)-($(C.north)-(C.south)$)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw,circle,minimum size=1.8cm] (C) at (0,0){};

\draw    ($($ (C.west)!.1!(C.east) $)-($(C.north)-(C.south)$)$)--($ (C.west)!.1!(C.east) $)
       --($ (C.west)!.25!(C.east) $)--($($ (C.west)!.3!(C.east) $)+(0,3pt)$)
       --($($ (C.west)!.4!(C.east) $)-(0,3pt)$)--($($ (C.west)!.5!(C.east) $)+(0,3pt)$)
       --($($ (C.west)!.6!(C.east) $)-(0,3pt)$)--($($ (C.west)!.7!(C.east) $)+(0,3pt)$)
       --($ (C.west)!.75!(C.east) $)--($ (C.west)!.9!(C.east) $)
       --($($ (C.west)!.9!(C.east) $)-($(C.north)-(C.south)$)$);
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```