# Arrow decoration in TIKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, decorations, feynmf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TikZ: How to draw an arrow in the middle of the line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3161/tikz-how-to-draw-an-arrow-in-the-middle-of-the-line)

I'd like to use Tikz for drawing Feynman diagrams. I found an example in [TeXample](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feynman-diagram/), but it looks inefficient.

One of the things I would appreciate is that the decoration `>` would appear midway of each part of the path, say

```
\draw[mypath] (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (2,1) -- (3,0);
```

to produce a path formed by three arrows.

**Questions**

- Is this possible?
- How should the style by defined?

Comment: This would be much more clear if you can provide a MWE. Every path and every segment of the path depends on how you define `every path/.style={...}` etc. Sorry for the misunderstanding but it's really not clear from your question. But the general answer is that yes it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at my answer to [TikZ: How to draw an arrow in the middle of the line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3161/tikz-how-to-draw-an-arrow-in-the-middle-of-the-line/69225#69225): I define a style to apply some styles to each segment of a path.

Comment: I guess it's better to close this as a duplicate. Nice answer by the way.

Comment: @percusse I didn't notice  Paul's solution. Thank you for pointing it out. Cheers.