# Drawing a complex figure in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw this figure in Tikz (apologies for poor image quality):

[image]

However, I can't quite figure out a good way to go about it. The only way I know how to draw this is as follows:

1. Declare a scope which includes arrows halfway along each line segment, and `\draw` each of the 14 line segments on the outside inside this scope.
2. Manually `\draw` the rest of the lines and label them accordingly.
3. Manually `\fill` the 8 shaded regions.
4. Add the two arcs on the sides and label one `\gamma`.

Surely this is not the most efficient method. Using the `calc` package might save me a little calculation, but not much time overall. The only other way I've thought to do this is define a command which draws each unshaded triangle, and another which draws each shaded one, but I'm not sure how to automate the label placement, or how to declare a scope within `newcommand` to use my method for getting arrows on the sides.

What is the best way to draw something like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This uses **Caramdir**'s solution from [How to draw an arrow in the middle of the line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3161/tikz-how-to-draw-an-arrow-in-the-middle-of-the-line)

### Code

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\octagonradius}{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\octagonbigradius}{\octagonradius/sin(67.5)}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[   midarrow/.style={thick,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}}
]
    \foreach \x in {1,...,8}
    {   \ifthenelse{\isodd{\x}}
        {\xdef\mysign{1}}
        {\xdef\mysign{-1}}
        \fill[red,opacity=0.4,shift={(0,\mysign*\octagonradius)}] (0,0) -- (45*\x+22.5:\octagonbigradius) -- (45*\x+67.5:\octagonbigradius) -- cycle;
        \fill[blue,opacity=0.4,shift={(0,\mysign*\octagonradius)}] (0,0) -- (45*\x+22.5:\octagonbigradius) -- (45*\x-22.5:\octagonbigradius) -- cycle;
        \draw[shift={(0,\mysign*\octagonradius)}] (0,0) -- node[label=45*\x+112.5:1] {} (45*\x+22.5:\octagonbigradius);
        \draw[shift={(0,\mysign*\octagonradius)}] (0,0) -- node[label=45*\x+157.5:0] {} (45*\x+67.5:\octagonbigradius);
    }
    \foreach \x in {0,...,6}
    {   \ifthenelse{\isodd{\x}}
        {\xdef\mysign{1}}
        {\xdef\mysign{-1}}
        \draw[midarrow,shift={(0,\mysign*\octagonradius)}] (45*\x-22.5:\octagonbigradius) -- (45*\x-67.5:\octagonbigradius);
        \draw[midarrow,shift={(0,-1*\mysign*\octagonradius)}] (45*\x+112.5:\octagonbigradius) -- (45*\x+157.5:\octagonbigradius);
    }
    \draw[shift={(0,\octagonradius)}] (247.5:\octagonbigradius) -- (292.5:\octagonbigradius);
    \draw[very thick,->] (-\octagonbigradius,\octagonbigradius) to[bend right=40] node[left] {Y} (-\octagonbigradius,-\octagonbigradius);
    \draw[very thick,->] (\octagonbigradius,-\octagonbigradius) to[bend right=40] node[right] {Y} (\octagonbigradius,\octagonbigradius);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: I think I see the general strategy you're using, but I don't understand what `\xdef\mysign{1}` is doing.

Comment: @AlexBecker: `mysign` is set to 1 if x is odd and to -1 if it is even. This is used for the `shift` of the drawing commands, so shifted up or shifted down. It would have also been possible to do `if x odd then draw[red,shift up] else draw[red, shift down]`, but I didn't like putting the draw commands twice.

Comment: Thanks very much. I actually just realized that after staring at the code some more. I'm going to try using this method to make a similar drawing and see how things work out.

Answer (score 4):

When you have something that is very periodic a `\foreach` loop is very encouraging. I have here shown a simple picture given you enough for you to start, but still limited to not be complete.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  ->-/.style={%
      postaction={decorate},decoration={%
          markings,mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{stealth}}%
      }%
  },->-/.default=.5,%
  -<-/.style={
      postaction={decorate},decoration={%
          markings,mark=at position #1 with {\arrowreversed{stealth}}%
      }%
  },-<-/.default=.5]
  \foreach \angle [count=\i] in {22.5,67.5,...,337.5} {
      \ifodd\i\relax
      \draw[-<-] (0,0) -- node{0} (\angle-45:2cm) -- (\angle:2cm) -- cycle;
      \else
      \fill[->-] (0,0) -- node{1} (\angle-45:2cm) -- (\angle:2cm) -- cycle;
      \fi
  }
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

I have chosen to use decorations as arrows. In that way it is easier to maintain and reuse the code. The style `->-` defaults to drawing an arrow halfway on the path. And `-<-` draws one reversed. 
In order to get the 1 and 0 on the curve you need to use the node path halfway on the path.

The crude result:

[image]

Comment: I hadn't seen loops in TeX before. Thanks for the answer, it should help me with some of the other stuff I have to TeX.