# Decorate path with arrows at nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, paths, decorations

Standalone example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[black, very thick] plot[smooth] coordinates {(4,1) (2,2) (1,3) (2,4) (4,3)};

  \node[fill=green!60, inner sep=3pt, circle, draw] at (4, 1) {};
  \node[fill=green!60, inner sep=3pt, circle, draw] at (2, 2) {};
  \node[fill=green!60, inner sep=3pt, circle, draw] at (1, 3) {};
  \node[fill=green!60, inner sep=3pt, circle, draw] at (2, 4) {};
  \node[fill=green!60, inner sep=3pt, circle, draw] at (4, 3) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

I like to have arrows before each node point at the node on all nodes in the path.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [TikZ: How to draw an arrow in the middle of the line?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3161/14500)

Comment: No, I do not think this is a duplicate. Here it is a complete curve which passes behind the nodes. I also tried with path between nodes (it also works) but then you lose the effect of the curve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on my own answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74986/how-to-decorate-a-path-with-arrows-at-certain-coordinates), I got the following result:

[image: arrow before nodes]

Positioning of the arrows is done automatically according to the list of points that appears at the beginning of the code. Here we go:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\newcounter{counter}
\newcommand\getpoint[1]{\csuse{point#1}}
\def\pointlist{}
\newcommand\setpoint[2]{
    \node (point#1) at #2 {};
    \csxdef{point#1}{#2} 
    \edef\pointlist{\pointlist \getpoint{#1}}
}
\newcommand\addpoint[1]{\stepcounter{counter} \setpoint{\thecounter}{#1}}

\newcounter{anothercounter}
\newcommand\getanotherpoint[1]{\csuse{anotherpoint#1}}
\def\anotherpointlist{}
\newcommand\setanotherpoint[2]{
    \csxdef{anotherpoint#1}{#2} 
    \edef\anotherpointlist{\anotherpointlist \getanotherpoint{#1}}
}
\newcommand\addanotherpoint[1]{\stepcounter{anothercounter} \setpoint{\theanothercounter}{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \addpoint{(4,1)}
        \addpoint{(2,2)}
        \addpoint{(1,3)}
        \addpoint{(2,4)}
        \addpoint{(4,3)}

        \draw [name path = curve 1, black, very thick] plot [smooth] coordinates {\pointlist};
        \path [name intersections={of=curve 1 and curve 1, name=i, total=\t, sort by = curve 1}] node {\xdef\totalone{\t}};

        \edef\mypath{}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\lastbutone}{\totalone - 1}
        \foreach \k in {1, ..., \lastbutone}
        {
            \xdef\mypath{\mypath (i-\k) -- }
        }
        \edef\mypath{\mypath (i-\totalone)}

        \newdimen\xone
        \newdimen\yone
        \newdimen\xtwo
        \newdimen\ytwo

        \foreach \q in {1, ..., \thecounter}
        {
            \pgfextractx{\xtwo}{\pgfpointanchor{point\q}{center}}
            \pgfextracty{\ytwo}{\pgfpointanchor{point\q}{center}}

            \foreach \p in {1, ..., \totalone}
            {
                \pgfextractx{\xone}{\pgfpointanchor{i-\p}{center}}
                \pgfextracty{\yone}{\pgfpointanchor{i-\p}{center}}

                \ifboolexpr{
                    test {\ifdimless{\xtwo - 0.6pt}{\xone}} and test {\ifdimless{\xone}{\xtwo + 0.6pt}}
                    and
                    test {\ifdimless{\ytwo - 0.6pt}{\yone}} and test {\ifdimless{\yone}{\ytwo + 0.6pt}}
                }{
                    \setanotherpoint{\q}{\p}
                }{
                }
            }
        }

        \foreach \k in {1, ..., \thecounter}
        {
            \node [
                circle
                , fill = green!60
                , inner sep = 3pt
            ] (thepoint \k) at (i-\getanotherpoint{\k}) {};
        }

        \foreach \k in {2, ..., \thecounter}
        {
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\lastpoint}{\getanotherpoint{\k} - 5}
            \draw [decorate, decoration = {markings, mark = at position -0.01pt with {
                \node [
                    single arrow
                    , fill = red
                    , anchor = east
                    , minimum size = 2mm
                    , inner sep = 1pt
                    , single arrow head extend = 2pt
                    , transform shape
                ]{};
            }}] (i-\lastpoint) -- (thepoint \k) {};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

### EDIT

OBS: I changed the style of the arrow just to be more like the provided example.

Well, just to complete my answer, now I will give a little more detail. Tripplet said there was a space between the arrow and cículo and he was right, as can be seen here:

[image: Separation between circle and arrow]

The distance between the circle and the arrow was given by the contour line, which was not being drawn. This is easily fixed as you can see:

```
\foreach \k in {1, ..., \thecounter} {
    \node [
        circle
        , draw = green      % added
        , fill = green!50
        , inner sep = 3pt
    ] (thepoint \k) at (i-\getanotherpoint{\k}) {};
}
```

And the result is

[image: Circle with border drawn]

But, if desired the arrow gets further into the circle, one can make the following changes:

```
\foreach \k in {1, ..., \thecounter} {
    \node [
        circle
        , inner sep = 2.75pt
    ] (thepoint \k) at (i-\getanotherpoint{\k}) {};
    \node [
        circle
        , draw = green
        , fill = green!50
        , inner sep = 3pt
    ] at (i-\getanotherpoint{\k}) {};
}
```

And you will get:

[image: Arrow futher into circle]

Comment: I don't like the point, that the arrows are not curved and look a little out of place.

Comment: @tripplet: Could you explain a little better? What do you mean by out of place? The arrows are being placed along the path. The distance is calculated directly by Tikz. I have no influence in this point.

Comment: To me the arrows don't look like they are part of the path and separately put over it. Maybe thats just a personal thing, the solution is just as good as the other, but I personally just like the look of madit's solution a little more ;)

Comment: @tripplet, take another look. ;)

Comment: awesome thats exactly what I wanted, thanks @tecepe. I didn't expect this to end this in so much code, good I asked, I would have never figured this out myself.

Answer (score 5):

Here a "*solution*" derived from [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69225/14500) to [TikZ: How to draw an arrow in the middle of the line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3161).

The result is correct ***but with errors during compilation***. Without `smooth`, there is no error.

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
  % style to apply some styles to each segment of a path
  on each segment/.style={
    decorate,
    decoration={
      show path construction,
      moveto code={
      },
      lineto code={
        \path [#1]
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
      curveto code={
        \path [#1] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)
        .. controls
        (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
        ..
        (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
      closepath code={
        \path [#1]
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
    },
  },
  % style to add an arrow
  mid arrow/.style={decorate,decoration={
      markings,
      mark=at position .93 with {\arrow[#1]{stealth}},
    },
  },
  % style to add a circle
  point/.style={decorate,decoration={
      markings,
      mark=at position .99 with {\node[#1,thin,circle,inner sep=2pt]{};},
    },
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[black, very thick,
  postaction={on each segment={mid arrow={fill=red,line width=3pt}}},
  postaction={on each segment={point={fill=lime,draw=green!50!black}}},
  ]
  plot[smooth] coordinates {(4,1) (2,2) (1,3) (2,4) (4,3)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is `Dimension too large` the compile error you are referring to?  That's what I get if the `smooth` option is left in there.

Comment: @PeterGrill Exact. I'm pretty sure it comes from the `markings` library...

Comment: The smooth option is pretty important to me so not the best solution, but good suggestion.

Comment: @tripplet The bug with `smooth` option and `markings` library can and must be fixed. I just need time... ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Try with

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={markings,% 
 mark=at position .270  with {\arrow[red,line width=3pt]{>}},%
 mark=at position .470  with {\arrow[red,line width=3pt]{>}},%
 mark=at position .680  with {\arrow[red,line width=3pt]{>}},%
 mark=at position .980  with {\arrow[red,line width=3pt]{>}},%
 }]
  \draw[
     black, thick,postaction={decorate} ]%
     plot[smooth] coordinates {(4,1) (2,2) (1,3) (2,4) (4,3)};

  \node[fill=green!60, inner sep=3pt, circle, draw] at (4, 1) {};
  \node[fill=green!60, inner sep=3pt, circle, draw] at (2, 2) {};
  \node[fill=green!60, inner sep=3pt, circle, draw] at (1, 3) {};
  \node[fill=green!60, inner sep=3pt, circle, draw] at (2, 4) {};
  \node[fill=green!60, inner sep=3pt, circle, draw] at (4, 3) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It works home with `pdftex`. I havent any trick to find the correct position ... except try and error ;-)

Comment: Seems to be the best looking solution so far, except the fact, that I have to position the arrows by try and error. Maybe someone knows a solution to this?