# Decorate path precisely on intersection(s) with TikZ - avoiding crossing lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-decorations

How can I (Is it possible to) make a decoration style which takes as arguement one path (or possibly more, that would be perfect), and makes an arc, snake, ellipse (whatever), where the paths intersect each other? I've seen These two ways of doing this:

- [Intersection of 2 lines not really connected in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111660/intersection-of-2-lines-not-really-connected-in-tikz/111674#111674)
- [Example: Handling the crossover of intersecting lines](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/line-junction/)

But they are rather exaustive especially if one path has more than one intersection with the other, then, this can become very exaustive. Furthemore, they're mostly restricted to straight lines.

## First attempt:

Inspired by Emma's answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335738/making-multiple-lines-connected-by-nodes-to-appear-as-one-continuous-line) I was able to put together a MWE, but it's still far from good as it does not support curved paths and the lines do not join (if multiple coordinates are use to construct the path). Other than that, there's no control over the jump size...

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,intersections,calc}
\tikzset{
    over path/.style={
        decoration={show path construction, lineto code={
          \path[name path=this path] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
          \path[name intersections={of=this path and #1, total=\t}, /utils/exec={\global\let\t=\t}]%
                                    let \n1={int(\t+1)} in%
                                    (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) coordinate (int-0)%
                                    foreach \i in {1,...,\n1}{%
                                      \ifnum \i<\n1%
                                          (intersection-\i) coordinate (int-\i)%
                                      \else
                                          (\tikzinputsegmentlast) coordinate (int-\n1)%
                                      \fi};
          \draw (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) foreach[remember=\i as \last (initially 0)] \i in {1,...,\t}{%
            let \p1=($(int-\last)-(int-\i)$), \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)}, \n2={abs(4pt)}, \n3={\i+1}  in%
            [rounded corners=\n2/4] -- ($(int-\last)!\n1-\n2!(int-\i)$) to[bend left=90, looseness=1.7] ($(int-\last)!\n1+\n2!(int-\n3)$)} -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
                }
            },
            decorate
        }
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (a) at (-1,0.5);
    \coordinate (b) at (8,0.5);
    \coordinate (c) at (3,-0.5);
    \draw[ultra thick, name path=sine, domain=-1:8, smooth, samples=50] plot (\x,{sin(\x r)});
    \draw[over path=sine] (a) -- (c) |- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Bad line join:

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the `knots` library?

Comment: @cfr, Didn't know about that. Just looked at it now (briefly), it seems to me that it can compute the intersections of paths and put one over another, but does not do the "jumping over". That's really quite useful, thank's for the reference, but I think it can't give me what I'm looking for... =/

Comment: I really meant at how it does it - not that it would do exactly what you need.

Comment: @cfr, ohh yes! Apparently there is a very good way to do what I want. `knots` library uses the `spath3` package to keep track of the constructed path (which is part of what I wish). Unfortunately the documentation is not so straightfoward -- at least for me. I'll try to make something out of it, thanks for the reference!

Comment: If you get stuck, I'd suggest asking a question with the library name in the title to catch its author's attention ...

Comment: If you use `line cap=round` then there is not join problem.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Maybe someone else. I have seen the code of tikzcircuit and they do magic.

Comment: @CarLaTeX although I appreciate Symbol1's suggestion, I've thought of it but intentionally left it out because for the question in matter that's to be considered a "hack". What I'd really like is to have is the path entirely decorated as a normal decoration works... I've learned that the "hole" is deeper than what I've imagined ;P so I dropped it... Maybe someone else can go further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a technique using the [`spath3`](http://ctan.org/pkg/spath3) library.  It works as follows:

1. Split the over path where it intersects the under path.
2. Insert gaps in the over path at these points.
3. Splice in an arc into these gaps (joining it to the existing path so the joins are seamless).
4. Split the under path where it intersects with the new over path.
5. Insert small gaps in the under path at these points.

The development version (on [`github`](https://github.com/loopspace/spath3) -- soon to be on CTAN) contains a version of the splicing code that ensures that the arc is always "upright".  This will be on CTAN fairly soon.

Here's the result:

[image: Bridges over sine waves]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/334483/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spath3,intersections}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (-1,0.5);
\coordinate (b) at (8,0.5);
\coordinate (c) at (3,-0.5);
\path[
  ultra thick,
  spath/save=sine,
  domain=-1:8,
  smooth,
  samples=50
] plot (\x,{sin(\x r)});
\path[spath/save=over] (a) -- (c) |- (b);

\path[spath/save=arc] (0,0) arc[radius=1cm, start angle=180, delta angle=-180];

\tikzset{
  spath/split at intersections with={over}{sine},
  spath/insert gaps after components={over}{8pt},
  spath/join components with={over}{arc},
  spath/split at intersections with={sine}{over},
  spath/insert gaps after components={sine}{4pt},
}

\draw[spath/use=sine];
\draw[spath/use=over];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

Here's a solution. It's fully automatic and should well even for curved lines. The notation is `avoid intersection={name of other path}{drawing options}`. It finds the list of intersection points, then executes a decoration that measures the distance to the next intersection point and when gets close, does an evasive maneuver. Using the options `avoid intersect amplitude`, `avoid intersect width`, and `avoid intersect offset` you can adjust the evasive maneuver.

It's not perfect. It is very slow (on my computer, the two examples take 1.4 seconds and 3.8 seconds respectively), which may be unavoidable. Also, if you include the `smooth` option in the second example below it breaks with a "dimension too large" error. I have no idea why. I think the output looks very good.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  avoid intersection amplitude/.store in=\avint@amplitude,
  avoid intersection width/.code={\edef\avint@width{\dimexpr#1/2}},
  avoid intersection offset/.store in=\avint@offset,
  avoid intersection has corners/.code={\pgfdecoratepathhascornerstrue}
}
\def\avint@amplitude{5pt}
\def\avint@width{5pt}
\def\avint@offset{0pt}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{avoidintersect}{initial}{
  \state{initial}[width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength/100,next state=measure]
  {
    \gdef\avint@intersectionnumber{1}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointorigin}
  }

  \state{measure}[width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength/100,next state=wait,auto corner on length=2pt,
               persistent postcomputation=\let\pgf@decorate@next@state\avint@smuggle@pgf@decorate@next@state]
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointorigin}
    \pgfgettransform\avint@temptransform
    \pgftransforminvert
    \pgfpointintersectionsolution{\avint@intersectionnumber}
    \pgf@pos@transform{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}
    \pgfmathveclen{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}
    \pgfsettransform\avint@temptransform
    \xdef\avint@waitcycles{\the\numexpr\dimexpr\pgfmathresult pt-\avint@width*3-\avint@offset\relax/\dimexpr\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength/100\relax}
    \ifnum\avint@waitcycles>50\relax\gdef\avint@waitcycles{50}\fi
    \global\let\avint@smuggle@pgf@decorate@next@state\pgf@decorate@next@state        
    \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt<\dimexpr\avint@width+\avint@offset\relax
        \gdef\avint@smuggle@pgf@decorate@next@state{zig}
    \else
        \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt<\dimexpr\avint@width*2+\avint@offset\relax
            \gdef\avint@smuggle@pgf@decorate@next@state{measure}    
        \fi
    \fi        
  }

  \state{wait}[width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength/100,next state=measure,repeat state=\avint@waitcycles,auto corner on length=2pt]{
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointorigin}
  } 

  \state{zig}[width=\avint@width, next state=zag]{
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfqpoint{\avint@width}{0cm}}{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\avint@amplitude}}{\pgfqpoint{\avint@width}{\avint@amplitude}}
  }
  \state{zag}[width=\avint@width, next state=measure,
              persistent postcomputation=\let\pgf@decorate@next@state\avint@smuggle@pgf@decorate@next@state]{
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfqpoint{\avint@width}{\avint@amplitude}}{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0cm}}{\pgfqpoint{\avint@width}{0pt}}
    \xdef\avint@intersectionnumber{\the\numexpr\avint@intersectionnumber+1}
    \global\let\avint@smuggle@pgf@decorate@next@state\pgf@decorate@next@state
    \ifnum\avint@intersectionnumber>\pgfintersectionsolutions
      \gdef\avint@smuggle@pgf@decorate@next@state{done}
    \fi
  }

  \state{done}[width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength/100,auto corner on length=2pt]{
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointorigin}
  }

  \state{final}{\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}}
}    

\tikzset{
    avoid intersection/.code 2 args={
        \pgfkeysalso{name path=avint@temp,draw=none}
        \expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@postactions\expandafter{\tikz@postactions
            \pgfintersectionsortbyfirstpath
            \tikz@intersect@namedpaths
            \pgfintersectionofpaths
                {\pgfsetpath\tikz@intersect@path@name@avint@temp}
                {\expandafter\pgfsetpath\csname tikz@intersect@path@name@#1\endcsname}
            \begin{pgfdecoration}{{avoidintersect}{\pgfdecoratedpathlength}}
            \pgfsetpath\tikz@intersect@path@name@avint@temp
            \end{pgfdecoration}
            \pgfgetpath\avint@temp@path
            \pgfusepath{discard}
            \draw[/utils/exec={\tikz@addmode{\pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath\avint@temp@path}},#2](0,0)rectangle (0,0);%
        }
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (a) at (-1,0.5);
    \coordinate (b) at (8,0.5);
    \coordinate (c) at (3,-0.5);
    \draw[ultra thick, name path=sine, domain=-1:8, smooth, samples=50] plot (\x,{sin(\x r)});
    \draw[avoid intersection={sine}{white,double=black},avoid intersection has corners] (a) -- (c) |- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (a) at (-1,0.5);
    \coordinate (b) at (8,0.5);
    \coordinate (c) at (3,-0.5);
    \draw[ultra thick,name path=line] (a) -- (c) |- (b);
    \draw[avoid intersection={line}{white,double=black},avoid intersection offset=1.5pt,domain=-1:8,samples=50] plot (\x,{sin(\x r)});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here's the output:
[image]

You can see that the line join works fine:
[image]

Comment: Wow! Very nice, thank you for all the effort! For me the time is not really an issue, one can suppress the decorations for the draft and only apply it in the end... Any idea why the joins are a little bit weird? They look... broken?

Comment: @GuilhermeZanotelli Should be fixed. I added the option `avoid intersection has corners` for this. The bottom corner still isn't quite as good as an undecorated corner, but I can't make it any better.

Comment: Oh yeah. Now it's perfect! Real nice job, thanks for that! Now my circuit drawings will be just as i want them to be without such great efforts... =D