# Making multiple lines connected by nodes to appear as one continuous line?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I've never used TikZ and certainly not for drawing graphs. Based on your experience with TikZ, would you say I shouldn't try to draw the graph below with it?

Look at the combinations of lines consisting of an arrowed line, a dotted line and a line ending with a black dot (e.g. there's one between A1 and Q1). I assume that I could draw such by drawing 3 different lines, but can I keep them aligned so that they would appear as a straight and continuous path? Or will there be visible joints?

I'd prefer simplicity, so it might be easiest to somehow group lines together, but is that even possible?

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and much more likely that some one will try to help you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are going to be making many of these complex arrows (as you seem to be doing) you can also use path replacing to automate your arrow style:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows, decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{
  myarrow/.style={
    decoration={show path construction, lineto code={
      \path (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) to coordinate[pos=.2] (mid1) coordinate[pos=.75] (mid2) (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      \draw[-stealth] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) to (mid1);
      \draw[dashed, shorten <=3pt] (mid1) to (mid2);
      \draw[-*, shorten >=2pt] (mid2) to (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      }},
    decorate
    },
  label1/.style={pos=.2, font=\footnotesize},
  label2/.style={pos=.9, font=\tiny}
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (C) at (0,0)  [draw=red, circle, fill=gray!50]{C} ;
\node (X) at (1,4)  [draw=black, circle]{X} ;
\node (Y) at (25:4)  [draw=black, circle]{Y} ;
\draw[myarrow] (C) to node[label1, right] {0,7} node[label2, right] {0,65} (X);
\draw[myarrow] (C) to node[label1, below] {0,4} node[label2, below] {0,35} (Y);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: funky arrows]

Comment: Reusable styles. Nice, but what does "to coordinate[pos=.2] (mid1)" mean?

Comment: It finds the point 2/10 of the way from `(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)` (the starting point of the styled segment) to `(\tikzinputsegmentlast)` (the endpoint of the styled segment) and labels it `(mid1)` so that that coordinate can be used later.

Comment: +1! +4 if possible... At a first glance I thought I'd see a huge code as a solution, great use of TikZ capabilieties!!

Answer (score 3):

The following has a 2cm arrow, a one cm line ending in a circle in a straight line between two nodes, with the remainder drawn with dots.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepgflibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (C) at (0,0)  [draw=red,circle, fill=gray!50, align=center, text width=30pt,line width=2pt,outer sep = 2pt]{C} ;
\node (X) at (3,7)  [draw=black,circle,  align=center, text width=20pt,line width=2pt,outer sep = 2pt]{X} ;
\draw [->] (C) --  ($(C)!2cm!(X)$);
\draw [dotted] ($(C)!2.1cm!(X)$) -- ($(X)!2.1cm!(C)$);
\draw [-{Circle}] ($(X)!2cm!(C)$) --  (X);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta}`?

Comment: Looks promising.. first there would be setting of node positions and then drawing of a line having 3 different parts between them. I guess I understand what "($(C)!2.1cm!(X)$)" means, but what kind of purpose do those exclamation marks have? Manual seems like reading it could be exhausting.

Comment: @cfr not sure what the question is (this is first tikzpicture I've written:-) as far as I understand I need `calc` for the `!` syntax and `arrows.meta`  for `-{Circle}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, this is what you get for not using `picture`... I think what @cfr means is that you can load both libraries in just one call, like packages...

Comment: ^^ What @GuilhermeZ.Santos said. But more than that, it seemed confusing to use `\usetikzlibrary` for one and `\usepgflibrary` for the other and I wasn't sure why you'd done that. If you want to load them separately, you can just use `\usetikzlibrary` twice. I guess I'd use the Ti*k*Z interface where possible, when loading Ti*k*Z, for much the same reasons I'd use LaTeX syntax when possible, when using LaTeX, at least when it is no more clunky or awkward. (I draw the line at doing this for `\if`s.)

Comment: @cfr I just searched the manual for how to make a circle tip on a line and that's the first thing I landed on, didn't occur to me to merge that with something I'd found earlier to do the calculation of distance along the line:-)

Comment: You didn't read the entire manual before answering, then?