# Is there a clever way of drawing/marking intersections of multiple paths in block diagrams automatically?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tkz-euclide, intersections

I'm trying to draw a block diagram with tikz and would like to match some kind of convention concerning the intersection of lines/paths. The convention says, that the marking/semicircle has to be at the line that is running vertically.
For that I edited a command **overlap** to my needs. Using `\overlap{master path}{slave path}` the slave path will get a semicircle at the intersection with the master path.

In my MWE the command works but can't distinguish if master/slave line runs horizontally or vertically at the intersection.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
%
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
%
\newcommand{\overlap}[2]{
    \path[name intersections={of= #1 and #2,sort by=#2, name=punkt, total=\t},/utils/exec={\global\let\t=\t}];
    \ifnum \t>0
    \foreach \s in {1,...,\t}{          
        % circle for intersections
        \path[name path global/.expanded =whitecirc-\s,draw=none,line width=0pt]
        (punkt-\s)circle(5.6705pt);
        
        % name intersections
        \path[name intersections={of=#2 and whitecirc-\s,sort by=#2,name=wb,total=\numwb},
        /utils/exec={\global\let\numwb=\numwb}];
        \ifnum \numwb>1

        % inner white circle
        \path[draw=white,fill=white, line width=0.2pt]
        (punkt-\s)circle(5.35pt); 
        
        % intersections if circle with other line
        \path[name intersections={of=#1 and whitecirc-\s,sort by=#2,name=wa}];

        % re-draw 2nd line (slave path)
        \draw[shorten <=-2pt,shorten >=-2pt](wa-1.center)--(wa-2.center);

        % draw arc
        \coordinate (A) at (wb-2);
        \coordinate (B) at (wb-1);
        \tkzInterCC[R](A,2.4mm)(B,2.4mm)
        \tkzGetPoints{X}{Y}
        \coordinate (Z) at ($(X)!0.5!(Y)$);

        % thicker white arc for hiding small part of slave path
        \tkzDrawArc[color=white,ultra thick, line cap=butt,shorten <=0.4pt,shorten >=0.4pt](Z,B)(A)
        % normal Arc (master path)
        \tkzDrawArc[color=black,line cap=butt](Z,B)(A)
        \fi
    }
    \fi
}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0,>=latex']
\draw[fill=white] (0,0) rectangle (6,9);
%
\foreach \i in {3,4,5} {
\coordinate (w\i) at (1,\i); \coordinate (e\i) at (5,\i);
\draw[->,name path=path\i] (w\i) --(e\i);
}
%
\foreach \i in {1,2,6,7,8} {
\node[circle,draw,align=center,fill=black,inner sep=0pt, minimum size = 3pt] (w\i) at(1,\i) {};
}
%
\coordinate (h1) at ($(w3)!0.4!(e3)$);\coordinate (h2) at ($(w3)!0.6!(e3)$);
\draw[->,name path=path2] (w2) -| (4,6) |- (2,6) |- (1,8);
\draw[->,name path=path1] (w1) -| (3,5) |- (w7);
%
\overlap{path2}{path1}
\overlap{path3}{path1}
\overlap{path4}{path1}
\overlap{path5}{path1}
%
\overlap{path3}{path2}
\overlap{path4}{path2}
\overlap{path5}{path2}
%
\node [draw,fill=red,fill opacity=0.4,rectangle,minimum size=1cm,anchor=center] at (2,7) {};
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: No distinction between vertical and horizontal master/slave segments]

Overall I don't know if there is a more clever way to **redraw intersections automatically**. Naming every path let's say `path1,path2,path3,...,pathN` and searching for every intersection within 2 `\foreach`-loops could be an approach.

```
\foreach \x in {1,2,3,4} 
\foreach \y in {2,3,4,5} 
    {
        \if\ifnum\x>\y T\else\ifnum\x=\y T\else F\fi\fi T%
        %  TRUE
        \break foreach
        \else
        %  FALSE
        \overlap{path\y}{path\x};
        \fi
    }
```

But using this loop leads to another problem which let's the circle flip randomly.
[image: Flipped semicircle while using foreach-loop]

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways such as using `shorten`, `postaction` after knowing intersection points.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\def\r{.35}
\draw[fill=pink] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);

\draw[<-] (-2,0)--(-\r,0) arc(180:0:\r)--(2,0)
--++(-90:2-\r) arc(90:-90:\r)--++(-90:1-\r);
\fill[pink]  (0,\r) circle(2pt);        
\fill[white] (2+\r,-2) circle(2pt);
\draw[<-] (-2,2)--++(0:2)--++(-90:4)--++(0:4)--++(-90:1);
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, doing it manually works fine. But since my actual block diagram has a bigger number of lines and intersections, an automated way of achieving this would be great.
I don't know how to use the `shorten` for that since it can only handle to shorten the path in the direction of end or start point.
Using `postaction` seems legit but I want to re-draw the intersections after all paths are drawn.

Comment: @Nivek In case you diagram has a bigger number of lines and intersections, then you cam make a `\newcommand` to shorten your code. Please see more here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570233/intersect-two-lines/570270#570270 and here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334483/decorate-path-precisely-on-intersections-with-tikz-avoiding-crossing-lines