# Draw an arrow on a closed path in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Like this, only it doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

 \draw [->] (0, 0) ellipse [x radius = 2, y radius = 3];
 \draw [->] (0, 0) -- (1, 0) -- (0, 1) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

(Edited, twice, to include an MWE that actually compiles, as requested).

Comment: Please could you provide a full MWE?

Comment: First you are missing the `\begin{tikzpicture}` and `\end{tikzpicture}`. Second, I think you have to use the `decorations` library. See for instance [TikZ: How to draw an arrow in the middle of the line?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3161/tikz-how-to-draw-an-arrow-in-the-middle-of-the-line).

Comment: Thank you, the `decorations` library did the trick, as explained in the other question.