# How to reduce the code when accenting several points with the \datavisualization … info[options]{code} …; command of TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-datavisualization

This question continuous my [another](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366838/how-to-add-arrow-tips-to-achieve-flow-direction-to-a-process-diagram-with-tikz).

See the code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[per-mode = fraction]{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization[scientific axes = {clean,
                                          end labels
                                         },
                       x axis = {label = $\frac{v}{\si{\cubic\m\per\kg}}$},
                       y axis = {label = $\frac{p}{\si{\bar}}$},
                       data/format = function,
                       visualize as smooth line/.list = {isentropic_press,
                                                         isobaric,
                                                         isentropic_decompress
                                                        }
                      ]
    data[set = isentropic_press] {var x : interval[.5 : 2];
                                  func y = 1 / \value x ^ 1.4;
                                 }
    data[set = isobaric] {var x : interval[.5 : 1];
                          func y = 1 / .5 ^ 1.4;
                         }
    data[set = isentropic_decompress] {var x : interval[1 : 2];
                                       func y = 1 / (\value x - .5) ^ 1.4;%-.5: shifts the function by - 0.5 to the right
                                      }
    %accents important points
    info {\draw (visualization cs:x = 2,
                                  y = {(1 / 2 ^ 1.4)}
                ) circle [radius = 1pt]
            node [right,
                  font = \footnotesize
                 ] {1};
         }
    info {\draw (visualization cs:x = .5,
                                  y = {(1 / .5 ^ 1.4)}
                ) circle [radius = 1pt]
            node [above,
                  font = \footnotesize
                 ] {2};
         }
    info {\draw (visualization cs:x = 1,
                                  y = {(1 / .5 ^ 1.4)}
                ) circle [radius = 1pt]
            node [above,
                  font = \footnotesize
                 ] {3};
         }
    info {\draw (visualization cs:x = 2,
                                  y = {(1 / 1.5 ^ 1.4)}
                ) circle [radius = 1pt]
            node [right,
                  font = \footnotesize
                 ] {4};
         };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The `info` lines (starts with the comment `%accents important points`) above looks already the same (only coordinates, alignment and text changes). Is there a way to reduce the amount of code when accenting several points?

The `\datavisualization ... info[options]{code} ...;` command is described on page 766 of the `TikZ & PGF` [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to put the point label information into the data? You can put it all into one `info` via a `/.list` argument, just like you did with the `visualize as` arguments. Generally, they are two separate steps: Draw the data graph and the annotation. Within `\datavisualization`, they are separate. If you _need_ to combine them, you would have to turn to `pgfplots`.

Comment: '[O]nly coordinates, alignment and text changes': so what doesn't change? I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hello @Huang_d and cfr! Thank you for your comments. Sorry for my unclear question. Huang_d yes, I wish to reduce the code which accents the important points. Something like _put it all into one `info`_, like you wrote, goes in the right direction. But I have difficulties to achieve it. I don't know how to do it via `/.list`. Shame on me! Can you please create an answer with the solution you described (put it all into one `info` via a `/.list`)? @cfr you are right, the most important things changes. I thought one can reduce the code, because it is already the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not that much to shorten. You can put it all into one `info` group, as in

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[change/.style={font=\footnotesize}]
[…]
info {\draw     (visualization cs: x = 2, y= {(1/2^1.4)}) circle [radius = 1pt] node [right, change] {1}
                (visualization cs: x = .5, y= {(1/.5^1.4)}) circle [radius = 1pt] node[above, change] {2}
                (visualization cs: x = 1, y= {(1/.5^1.4)}) circle [radius = 1pt] node[above, change] {3}
                (visualization cs: x = 2, y= {(1/1.5^1.4)}) circle [radius = 1pt] node[right, change] {4}
    ;};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I did not manage to put it into a list; But then again, it is only four points.
You can alternatively label the nodes as `node(A){}` and reference them outside of the `\datavisualization` environment for slightly more control over what is is doing. As far as I know, there is no "put something on the first/last data point" within `\datavisualization`, which is disappointing. Until that is implemented, you will have to manually address points of interest. After all, `tikz` does not know which points are special.

Comment: Hello @Huang_d! Thank you for your answer! Your solution is enough for me.