# It is possible to reuse TikZ code?

Tags: tikz-pgf, compiling, external-files

Let say one create the following figure and save it in a file `figure.tex`:

```tex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
                arrows.meta,
                bending,
                positioning
               }
\tikzset{
         > = Latex,
         arrows = {[bend]},
         signal/.style = coordinate,
         sum/.style = {
                       draw,
                       circle,
                       minimum size = 2mm
                      },
         block/.style = {
                         draw,
                         rectangle,
                         minimum height = 2em,
                         minimum width = 4em
                        },
         branch/.style = {
                          sum,
                          minimum size = 1mm,
                          fill = black
                         }
        }

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[auto]

    %placing the nodes
    \node[signal] (input) {};
    \node[sum, right = of input] (left sum) {};
    \node[block, right = of left sum] (controller) {$G_R$};
    \node[block, right = of controller] (system) {$G_S$};
    %connecting the controller and system to get the coordinates of u, its needed for the placement of the measurement block
    \draw
      [->] (controller) -- node[name = u] {$U$} (system);
    \node[block, above = of system] (dynamic of disturbances) {$G_D$};
    \node[signal, left = of dynamic of disturbances] (disturbances) {};
    \node[sum, right = of system] (right sum) {};
    \node[branch, right = of right sum] (branch) {};
    \node[signal, right = of branch] (output) {};
    \node[sum, below = of branch] (lower sum) {};
    \node[signal, right = of lower sum] (measurement noise) {};
    \node[block] (measurement) at (u |- lower sum) {$G_M$};
    %connecting the nodes
    \draw
      [->] (input) -- node {$W$} (left sum);
    \draw
      [->] (left sum) -- node {$E$} (controller);
    \draw
      [->] (system) -- (right sum);
    \draw
      [->] (disturbances) -- node {$Z$} (dynamic of disturbances);
    \draw
      [->] (dynamic of disturbances) -| (right sum);
    \draw
      (right sum) -- (branch);
    \draw
      [->] (branch) -- node {$Y$} (output);
    \draw
      [->] (branch) -- (lower sum);
    \draw
      [->] (measurement noise) -- node[above] {$M$} (lower sum);
    \draw
      [->] (lower sum) -- (measurement);
    \draw
      [->] (measurement) -| node[pos = .95] {$-$} (left sum);

  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: figure 1]

Than one wish to load the file with `\input{figure}` and adding some code to it (without changing the file `figure.tex`), for example arrows, [see](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/517562/how-to-bend-a-curve-around-a-tikz-figure) my releated question. Is it possible?

Comment: do you know the [chains](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43038/36835) library? It is quite useful to draw control circuits.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why don't you put everything in a macro? In that example I am using a scope to be able to use `auto` in your graph and not outside, but this is not needed if you use `auto` everywhere...

In `iii.tex`:

```latex
%%% probably is better left in your main file, but nothing happens if you have this 
%%% multiple times
%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
%%%
%%% ditto
%%%
\usetikzlibrary{
                arrows.meta,
                bending,
                positioning
               }
\tikzset{
         > = Latex,
         arrows = {[bend]},
         signal/.style = coordinate,
         sum/.style = {
                       draw,
                       circle,
                       minimum size = 2mm
                      },
         block/.style = {
                         draw,
                         rectangle,
                         minimum height = 2em,
                         minimum width = 4em
                        },
         branch/.style = {
                          sum,
                          minimum size = 1mm,
                          fill = black
                         }
        }

\newcommand{\mygraph}{%
    \begin{scope}[auto]
    %placing the nodes
    \node[signal] (input) {};
    \node[sum, right = of input] (left sum) {};
    \node[block, right = of left sum] (controller) {$G_R$};
    \node[block, right = of controller] (system) {$G_S$};
    %connecting the controller and system to get the coordinates of u, its needed for the placement of the measurement block
    \draw
      [->] (controller) -- node[name = u] {$U$} (system);
    \node[block, above = of system] (dynamic of disturbances) {$G_D$};
    \node[signal, left = of dynamic of disturbances] (disturbances) {};
    \node[sum, right = of system] (right sum) {};
    \node[branch, right = of right sum] (branch) {};
    \node[signal, right = of branch] (output) {};
    \node[sum, below = of branch] (lower sum) {};
    \node[signal, right = of lower sum] (measurement noise) {};
    \node[block] (measurement) at (u |- lower sum) {$G_M$};
    %connecting the nodes
    \draw
      [->] (input) -- node {$W$} (left sum);
    \draw
      [->] (left sum) -- node {$E$} (controller);
    \draw
      [->] (system) -- (right sum);
    \draw
      [->] (disturbances) -- node {$Z$} (dynamic of disturbances);
    \draw
      [->] (dynamic of disturbances) -| (right sum);
    \draw
      (right sum) -- (branch);
    \draw
      [->] (branch) -- node {$Y$} (output);
    \draw
      [->] (branch) -- (lower sum);
    \draw
      [->] (measurement noise) -- node[above] {$M$} (lower sum);
    \draw
      [->] (lower sum) -- (measurement);
    \draw
      [->] (measurement) -| node[pos = .95] {$-$} (left sum);
\end{scope}}
```

and in your main file:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\input{iii}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
    \mygraph
    %% add things
    \draw[red] (measurement) circle[radius=2cm];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which gives the expected:

[image]

Comment: How about `\RequirePackage` for the `iii.tex`? (See [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19919/whats-the-difference-between-requirepackage-and-usepackage))

Comment: @gr4nt3d Yes, you can write it as a `.sty` file --- and the use `\usepackage{}` to call it. Depending on how much you share the specific code among prjects, can be worth the effort or not...