# Orientation on Graph

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can i make a graph with clockwise orientation in latex? Such as this image[image]

Comment: Have you already tried something you can show us? Its worthwile to have a look at the Ti*k*Z-package!

Comment: Well i have just made a normal graph but i have no clue how to make this.

Comment: How did you make the graph? Can you provide us with a minimal working example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With use of the `decorations.markings` and `patterns.meta` library, graph is drawing by `plot`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations.markings,
                patterns.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
decoration={
    markings,% switch on markings
    mark=between positions 0.2 and 0.8 step 0.2 with {\arrowreversed{stealth}}}
                        ]
\draw[postaction={decorate}, semithick,
      postaction={pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={3pt},line width=0.2pt]},pattern color=gray}]
    plot[domain=2:-2] (\x,4-\x*\x);
\node[right] at (1,3) {$y=4-x^2$};
\node at (1,1) {$D$};
\draw   (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[below left] {$x$}
        (0,-1) -- (0,5) node[below left] {$y$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. When I compile your code, though, the arrowheads are forward- rather than backward-pointing. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

This is an answer using [Ti*k*Z](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf), a comprehensive graphics package with, besides, an excellent documentation and tutorial included therein.

**Edit:** To place multiple arrows on the line, one can use Ti*k*Z' [`decorations`-library](http://vesta.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/ftp/pub/mirror/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page=646), as indicated by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3172/27717). This gives:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, quotes, positioning, decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=5mm, y=5mm, line width=0.75pt]
    \draw (0,-5) to["$y$" at end] (0,5);
    \draw (5,0) to["$x$" at start] (-5,0);
    \draw[
        pattern=north east lines, 
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position 0.2 with {\arrow{<}},
            mark=at position 0.6 with {\arrow{<}},
            mark=at position 0.8 with {\arrow{<}}
        },
        postaction=decorate
    ]   (-2,0)  parabola[bend at end] 
        (0,4)   coordinate (S) 
                parabola[at start] (2,0)
                to cycle;
    \node[right=9pt of S] {$y = 4 - x^2$};
    \node[cyan, fill=white, inner sep=1pt, rounded corners] at (0.7,1.3) {$D$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! is it possible to get those arrows more places on the graph and also back on the X-line to start point? With D inside

Comment: @AndersJensen See my edit for the arrows.

Comment: @AndersJensen Forgot about the *D*; added.