# Decorating an edge of a cycle in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

I would like to decorate the top edge of this shaded square with rounded corners by a little circle. (Hopefully, I would use the decor defined below. My trials and errors got me errors only.)

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, math, decorations.markings,calc,shapes.misc}
\usepgfmodule{decorations}

\begin{document}  

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[fill=gray, rounded corners, decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with {\draw[black, fill=white] circle[radius=2pt];}}]
        (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) NEED LITTLE CIRCLE HERE -- (1,0)-- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}        

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to "Decorating an edge of a cycle in tikz" is to use `edge[decorate]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}  

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[fill=gray, rounded corners, decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with {\draw[black, fill=white] circle[radius=2pt];}}]
        (0,0) -- (0,1) edge[decorate] (1,1) -- 
        (1,1)  -- (1,0)-- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}        
\end{document}
```

Here is an extended comment since there is another post which points out what had been pointed out several times already, e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430486): you can use a `pic` for the arrow. I'd like to complement the statement by adding that you need the `sloped` and `allow upside down` keys to make that work properly.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circ/.style={circle, draw, fill=white, inner sep=1.5pt},
    pics/arr/.style={code={\draw[-{Stealth[length=#1,fill=black]}] (-#1/2,0) -- 
    (#1/2,0); }},pics/arr/.default=1ex]
 % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430486   
 \draw[fill=gray, rounded corners]
        (0,0) -- (0,1) -- node[circ]{} (1,1) --
        pic[sloped,allow upside down]{arr} (1,0) -- 
        pic[sloped,allow upside down]{arr=1.2ex} cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Pumucki: Thanks! I tried something similar, but I didn't realize that I need to repeat (1,1) twice.

Comment: @Adam Yes, that's a property of `edge`, after the `edge` the path will continue where it was before the edge.

Comment: Sorry to say this, but this site sucks. I do not understand the voting behavior here at all. There is an interesting question, and I think that I answered it correctly. Note that decorations can be much more than just `decorations.markings`. Then there pops up another answer, which copies things from someone else, which adds something that works only for specific `decorations.markings` stuff, and is incomplete. At the time of writing my first post I was well aware of the possibility, but dismissed it because it does not answer the general question. Yet users upvote this plagiate like crazy.

Comment: So I decided to delete my account. Have fun with answers that do not answer the question, are copied from somewhere else without attribution, and are incomplete.

Answer (score 6):

A simple solution with using of `node` in the border where needed:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[fill=gray, rounded corners]
        (0,0) -- (0,1) -- node[circle, draw, fill=white, inner sep=1.5pt] {} (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:** Instead nodes with selected shapes, you can also use `pic` which can contain arrows etc. For example:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
arr/.pic = {\draw[-{Straight Barb[width=3pt]}] (-1pt,0) -- (1pt,0);}
                        ]
        \draw[fill=gray, rounded corners]
        (0,0) -- (0,1) -- pic {arr} (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! Frankly, I realized that I need to decorate another edge with a simple arrowhead and perhaps that will be easier with your solution. However, replacing `circle` with `arrow` or `\arrow{>}` does not work. Would you know how to make it work?

Comment: Proposed solution is simple with nodes with selected shapes or contents. For using of drawing elements as are arrows, the possible solution is to draw `pic` images and used it similarly as nodes.

Comment: @Adam, see addendum to answer.