# How to draw arrows on a grid?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, grids

[image]

I am a little new to LaTeX and I am trying to draw this grid with arrows using Ti*k*Z. Currently I am only able to draw the grid using :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=1cm, black] (-1.9,-1.9) grid (5.9,5.9);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However I am not able to do much more than that with my current skill level and I've tried to find a way online however it wasn't fruitful. I would appreciate any help on the matter.

In addition I want to be able to reproduce a drawing like the following one :[image]

The general structure of the image is not really crucial to me, what I want to learn is how to add numbers (or letters) like in the picture and how I can align two vertices next to each other.

Comment: Related: [TikZ: How to draw an arrow in the middle of the line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3161)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a pretty naïve approach.

To draw arrows, the `arrows.meta` module is quite useful, providing support for various arrow types. To enable it, put the following line in your preamble after you have loaded `tikz`.

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
```

Within the `tikzpicture`, you can add a scope, so that each time you can simply use `>` to refer to the arrow tip you want. For example, below I shall use `Stealth`.

```
\begin{scope}[>=Stealth]
    ...
\end{scope}
```

You can then draw the lines first:

```
\draw (0,0) -- (0, 1);
\draw (0,0) -- (0,-1);
\draw (0,0) -- ( 1,0);
\draw (0,0) -- (-1,0);
```

[image]

An arrow can be drawn like

```
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0.6,0);
```

[image]

Here the arrow is placed at `(0.6,0)` (the line from `(0,0)` to `(0.6,0)` coincide with the line that you've drawn in the previous step). In the same way, you can draw an arrow of reversed direction:

```
\draw[>-] ( 0.6,0) -- (0,0);
```

[image]

Below is the complete code for a "c-type" arrow in your picture:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[>=Stealth]
        \draw (0,0) -- (0, 1);
        \draw (0,0) -- (0,-1);
        \draw (0,0) -- ( 1,0);
        \draw (0,0) -- (-1,0);
        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0, 0.6);
        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,-0.6);
        \draw[>-] ( 0.6,0) -- (0,0);
        \draw[>-] (-0.6,0) -- (0,0);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the grid with arrows, since the distribution of your arrows doesn't seem very regular, you might have to repeat the above steps to draw the arrows -- shouldn't be that hard.

But this is just a beginning, which works even with a minimal amount of Ti*k*Z knowledge. I'm not proud of my Ti*k*Z skill, there might be some clever methods that can produce such graphs with very simple commands -- I shall left it to the experts :)

---

Regarding the labeling, this is simple, you can use `\node`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (0, 1);
    \draw (0,0) -- (0,-1);
    \draw (0,0) -- ( 1,0);
    \draw (0,0) -- (-1,0);
    \node at (0.2, 0.6) {$1$};
    \node at (0.2,-0.6) {$2$};
    \node at ( 0.6,0.2) {$2$};
    \node at (-0.6,0.2) {$1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It was extremely helpful I was able to redo them and I am going to post the code for it !