# Music Conducting patterns using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

It is needed to replicate the following conducting patterns, the starting code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

Conducting patterns:

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[xshift=-7cm]
        %Lineas de 2 tiempos
        \node (point1) at (6,-4) {\textbf{1}};
        \draw[draw=red, line width=1pt,-stealth] (6,-0.3)--(6,-3.8);
        \node (point2) at (6.5,0) {\textbf{2}};
        \draw[draw=red, line width=1pt,-stealth] (6.5,-3.8)--(6.5,-0.3);
        \node [below of=point1] {\parbox{0.3\linewidth}{duple meter}};
\end{scope}
    
\begin{scope}
    %Lineas de 3 tiempos
    \node (point3) at (2,0) {\textbf{3}};
    \draw[draw=red, line width=1pt,-stealth] (2,-0.3)--(2,-4);
    \node (point1) at (2,-4.2) {\textbf{1}};
    \draw[draw=red, line width=1pt,-stealth] (2.1,-4.1)--(3.9,-2.2);
    \node (point2) at (4,-2) {\textbf{2}};
    \draw[draw=red, line width=1pt,-stealth] (3.9,-1.8)--(2.1,-0.2);
    \node [below of=point1] {\parbox{0.3\linewidth}{triple meter}};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=8cm]
    %Lineas de 4 tiempos
    \node (point4) at (2,0) {\textbf{4}};
    \draw[draw=red, line width=1pt,-stealth] (2,-0.3)--(2,-4);
    \node (point1) at (2,-4.2) {\textbf{1}};
    \draw[draw=red, line width=1pt,-stealth] (1.9,-4.1)--(0,-2.2);
    \node (point2) at (0,-2) {\textbf{2}};
    \draw[draw=red, line width=1pt,-stealth] (0.2,-2)--(3.9,-2);
    \node (point3) at (4,-2) {\textbf{3}};
    \draw[draw=red, line width=1pt,-stealth] (3.9,-1.8)--(2.1,-0.2);
    \node [below of=point1] {\parbox{0.3\linewidth}{quadruple meter}};
\end{scope}    

\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Current output:
[image: current]

Expected output:
[image: expected]

Comment: Maybe section "74.3 Curves" of the tikz manual could help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, bending, decorations.markings}

\tikzset{mytip/.tip={Stealth[width=3mm, length=3mm, inset=1pt]},
    midarrow/.style={decoration={markings, mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{mytip}}}, postaction={decorate}},
    midarrow/.default={.5}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt, line cap=round]
\draw[midarrow, looseness=1.4] (0,3)node[above]{Start} to[out=-90, in=240]node[below, pos=.8]{1} (3,1);
\draw[midarrow, -mytip] (3,1) to[out=210, in=-80]node[above right, pos=.4]{2} (1,2);
\node at (1.5,-1){duple meter};
\begin{scope}[xshift=4.5cm]
\draw[midarrow] (0,3)node[above]{Start} to (0,0) node[below]{1};
\draw[midarrow=.4, looseness=1.7] (0,0) to[out=80,in=260]node[below, pos=.8]{2} (3.5,2);
\draw[midarrow=.3, -mytip](3.5,2) to[out=200, in=280]node[above right, pos=.7]{3} (1,3);
\node at (1.75,-1){triple meter};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=11cm]
\draw[midarrow=.4] (0,3)node[above]{Start} to (.2,0) node[below]{1};
\draw[midarrow=.7, looseness=1.6] (.2,0) to[out=100, in=330] (-2,1.5)node[below]{2} ;
\draw[midarrow=.7] (-2,1.5) to [out=20, in=240]node[below, pos=.9]{3} (3,2);
\draw[-mytip](3,2) to[out=210, in=300]node[above right, pos=.7]{4} (1,3);
\node at (.25,-1){quadruple meter};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the usage of `\arrow{mytip}` ! The code is neat!

Answer (score 5):

With the comment of samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz and the post [TikZ: How to draw an arrow in the middle of the line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3161/tikz-how-to-draw-an-arrow-in-the-middle-of-the-line), we obtain

[image]

**The code**

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669617/music-conducting-patterns-using-tikz

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
%
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3161/tikz-how-to-draw-an-arrow-in-the-middle-of-the-line
%
% code of Caramdir
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick,decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}}
  ] 
\node [font=\bfseries] (s) at (0,0) {Start};
\node [font=\bfseries] (a) at (6,-4) {1};
\node [font=\bfseries] (b) at (4,-1) {2};
\path (s) edge [out=-90,in=225,postaction={decorate}] (a);
\path (a) edge [-stealth,out=200,in=-90,postaction={decorate}] (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `a` and `b` should be coordinates.