# How to use tikz for sensor and actuator diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

The code is below.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}    
\usepackage[left=20mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm,right=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}  % for drawing pictures
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes.geometric, arrows}
\begin{document} 


\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, 
                node distance = 15mm and 19mm,
                start chain = going right,
                arr/.style = {->},>=Latex,
                block/.style = {draw, minimum height=3em, minimum
                width=4em,align=center,fill=blue!20},
                sum/.style = {circle, draw, node contents={}},    
                        ]
                \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain, join=by arr}]        
                \coordinate (in);

                \node (n4) [block] {$K_m = 2 \times 10^{-1}$ \\ $N mV^{-1}$};

            \node (n5) [block] {$K_s = 5 \times 10^{-2}$ \\ $rad \hspace{1mm} N^{-1} m^{-1}$};
                \coordinate (out);

             \path (n4) to [below, pos=0.5,"$T$"] (n5)   (out) ;
              \path (n4) to [below, pos=0.5,"$V$"]  (in) ;

                \path (n5) to [below, pos=0.5,"$\theta$"]  (out) ;
                    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

This picture below is what I got from code above.

[image]

This below is what I want to achieve.

[image]

Comment: just add labels belov of nodes and missed  labels above/below of arrows ...

Comment: @Zakro I tried but filed to do it. Could you try it?

Comment: Fir you need to make your MWE compilable ...  missed are `begin{document}` etc. To node ad `label=below:text`. I will write an answer ASAP

Comment: @Zarko I have already added `begin{document}`

Comment: [TikZ: How to draw an arrow in the middle of the line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3161)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, I hadn't spare time earlier ...

A possible solution can be:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=20mm,vmargin=30mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}  % for drawing pictures
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations.markings,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
node distance = 1mm and 19mm,
 block/.style = {draw, fill=blue!20,
                 minimum height=3em, minimum width=4em, align=center,
                 label=below:#1
                 },
   sum/.style = {circle, draw, node contents={}},
%
   arr/.style = {-{Stealth[scale=1.6]}},
   ->-/.style = {decoration = {markings,mark=at position 0.5
                               with {\arrow[scale=1.6]{Stealth}}},
                 postaction={decorate}},
every edge quotes/.append style = {anchor=center, align=center}
                        ]
\coordinate (in);
\node (n4) [block=Motor,  right=of in] {$K_m=2\times 10^{-1}$ \\ \unit{N mV^{-1}}};
\node (n5) [block=Spring, right=of n4] {$K_s=5\times 10^{-2}$ \\ \unit{\radian\per\newton\per\metre}};
\coordinate[right=of n5] (out);
\draw       (in) edge [->-,"$V$\\ Volts"] (n4)
            (n4) edge [->-,"$T$\\ \unit{\newton\meter\second}"]   (n5)
            (n5) edge [arr, "$\theta$\\ rad"]  (out);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
A case when nodes "block" are in chain.

```
\usepackage[hmargin=20mm,vmargin=30mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,                % added
                decorations.markings,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
node distance = 1mm and 19mm,
  start chain = going right,
    CB/.style = {draw, fill=blue!20,   % ChainBlock
                 minimum height=3em, minimum width=4em, align=center,
                 on chain,             % added
                 label=below:#1
                 },
   sum/.style = {circle, draw, node contents={}},
%
   arr/.style = {-{Stealth[scale=1.6]}},
   ->-/.style = {decoration = {markings,mark=at position 0.5
                               with {\arrow[scale=1.6]{Stealth}}},
                 postaction={decorate}},
every edge quotes/.append style = {anchor=center, align=center}
                        ]
\coordinate[on chain] (in);  % added option "on chain"
\node (n4) [CB=Motor] {$K_m=2\times 10^{-1}$ \\ \unit{N mV^{-1}}};
\node (n5) [CB=Spring]{$K_s=5\times 10^{-2}$ \\ \unit{\radian\per\newton\per\metre}};
\coordinate[on chain] (out); % added option "on chain"
\draw       (in) edge [->-,"$V$\\ Volts"] (n4)
            (n4) edge [->-,"$T$\\ \unit{\newton\meter\second}"]   (n5)
            (n5) edge [arr, "$\theta$\\ rad"]  (out);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as before.

Comment: As I'm curious: how can we have the same stealth for the very last arrow?

Comment: @NBur, me too ... ah in `arr` style I forgot to add the same scaling Stealth as at `->-`. Corrected now. Thank you very much to point me on this.

Answer (score 3):

I added the `siunitx` package and the `calc` library.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}    
\usepackage[left=20mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm,right=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}  % for drawing pictures
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
  calc,
  chains,
  positioning,
  quotes,
  shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, 
      node distance = 15mm and 19mm,
      start chain = going right,
      arr/.style = {->},>=Latex,
      block/.style = {draw, minimum height=3em, minimum
        width=4em,align=center,fill=blue!20},
      sum/.style = {circle, draw, node contents={}},    
      ]
      \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain, join=by arr}]        
        \coordinate (in);
        
        \node (n4) [block] {$K_m = \num{2e-1}$\\ \unit{\newton\meter\per\volt}};
        
        \node (n5) [block] {$K_s = \num{5e-2}$ \\ \unit{\radian\per\newton\per\metre}};
        \coordinate (out);
        
      \end{scope}
      \node [below=1pt of n4] {Motor};
      \node [below=1pt of n5] {Spring};
      \node at ($(in)!.5!(n4.west)$) [label={above:$V$}, label={below:\unit{\volt}}] {};
      \node at ($(n4.east)!.5!(n5.west)$) [label={above:$T$}, label={below:\unit{\newton\meter}}] {};
      \node at ($(n5.east)!.5!(out)$) [label={above:$\theta$}, label={below:\unit{\radian}}] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you let the arrow in the middle of line? because mine is at the end of the line but the one from the desired one is in the middle

Comment: @kile you should accept Zarko's answer as it solve this point!