# Tikz: arrows midway in draw

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-arrows

I need to draw an arrow midway in a line.
MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw(1,1) -- (1,17);
        \draw(1,17)--(7,17)--(12,12)--(9,9);
        \draw (12,12)--(1,1);

        \coordinate (start) at (6,6);
        \coordinate (reflection) at (1,11);
        \coordinate (end) at (7,17);
        \draw [red] (start)--(reflection)--(end); 
        \node (b) at (0.7,11) {b};
        \node (c) at (7,17.2) {c};
        \node (a) at (6.1,5.9) {a};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I need an arrow both between node `(a)` and `(b)` and between `(b)` and `(c)`, and both arrows should be midway.
I tried something like

```
\draw [red] (start) edge [->] (reflection) (reflection) edge [->] (end)(end);
```

but in this way the arrows are at the end of the segment.

Current:
[image: current]

Comment: Can You add a hand draw of desired arrows?

Comment: Is this what you want? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3161/125871

Comment: @SandyG this works great, the only small problem is that I have to split the \draw command

Comment: Please refer to the decoration approach there: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3172/245790

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess that you looking for the following:

[image]

For arrows heads in the middle of line is used `decorations.markings` Ti*k*Z library:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations.markings
                }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
->-/.style = {decoration={markings,
              mark=between positions 0.25 and 0.75 step 0.5 with {\arrow{Triangle[scale=1.2]}}},
              postaction={decorate},
              semithick, draw=red
              },
                        ]
\draw (1,1) |- (7,17)--(12,12) -- (1,1);

\draw [->-] (6,6)   coordinate[label=-45:a] (a) -- 
            (1,11)  coordinate[label=180:b] (b) -- 
            (7,17)  coordinate[label=c]     (c);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I simplify drawing black lines. However, you can stick with your way of its drawing.

Comment: thank you that what i was looking for