How to draw a smooth curve with arrows on both of its ends with tikz?
I want to draw a curve with arrows, with the help of tikz package same as the one shown in the image. I tried so much but did not succeed. 
\documentclass{article}

%maths
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

%tikzpicture
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, shapes.geometric}

%pdfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

%colors
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Draw x_M vector
    \draw[{Circle[scale=1]}-{Stealth[scale=1]},line width=0.5mm] (2,0)--(3,3);
\node at (3,2) {$\Vec{x}_M$}; % Positioning the \Vec{x}_M label slightly upward

    % Draw x_0 vector
    \draw[-{Stealth[scale=1]},line width=0.5mm] (2,0)--(2,4.3);
    \node at (2.29,3) {$\Vec{x}_0$}; % Positioning the \Vec{x}_0 label slightly upward

    % Draw straight line representing \rho
    \draw[line width=0.5mm] (3,3)--(2,4.3) node[midway,above right=-3pt] {$\rho$};

    % Draw t_0 vector
    \draw[-{Stealth[scale=1]},line width=0.5mm] (2,4.3)--(4,5.5) node[midway,above left=-2pt] {$\Vec{t}_0$};

    % Draw circle centered at (3,3) with radius 1.6
    \draw[line width=0.5mm] (3,3) circle [radius=1.6];

    % Smooth curve touching (2,4.3)
    \draw[{Stealth[scale=1]}-{Stealth[scale=1]},thick, smooth,line width=0.5mm] plot coordinates {(0,2) (2,4.3) (5.3,5.3)};

\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}


Take a look at this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3172/6880 .

What does the curve represent? If it is a mathematical construct, then you could plot it with a parametric plot path  - otherwise, approximating it with coordinates will be unexact. To do the arrows, use the decorations.markings tikzlibrary.

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, ext.topaths.arcthrough, decorations.markings}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick]
\fill (-1,-3) circle[radius=3pt];
\draw[-Stealth] (-1,-3) -- (0,0) node[right, pos=0.7] {$\Vec{x}_M$};
\draw[-Stealth] (-1,-3) -- (130:1.6) node[right, pos=0.7] {$\Vec{x}_0$};
\draw (0,0) -- (130:1.6) node[midway, above right=-2pt] {$\rho$};
\draw[-Stealth] (130:1.6) -- +(40:2.5) node[midway, above left=-2pt] {$\Vec{t}_0$};
\draw (0,0) circle[radius=1.6];
\draw[
decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.2 with {\arrow{Stealth}}, mark=at position 0.8 with {\arrow{Stealth}}},
postaction={decorate},
] ([shift={(240:3)}] 130:1.6) to[arc through={clockwise,(130:1.6)}] ([shift={(20:3)}] 130:1.6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Purely for comparison, here is a version in Metapost, the drawing language built into lualatex.
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
% define the radius of the circle
numeric rho;
rho = 72;

% define the x_m vector, and calculate x_0
pair xm, xz;
xm = 140 dir 70;
xz = (0, ypart xm + (rho +-+ xpart xm));

% calculate paths for the circle, the arc, and the tangent.
% Note that it is convenient to rotate the circle so that point 0 of
% the path is at xz.  Note how the direction of the arc is reversed 
% with `subpath(1, -1)`

path c, a, t;
c = fullcircle rotated angle (xz-xm) scaled 2 rho shifted xm;
a = subpath(1, -1) of fullcircle rotated angle (xz-xm) scaled 4 rho shifted point 4 of c;
t = point 0 of c -- point 0 of c shifted -60 unitvector(direction 0 of c);

% thin arrow heads
ahangle := 30;
   
% draw the lines and arrows

draw xm -- xz withcolor 2/3 blue;
draw c withcolor 2/3 red; 

drawarrow subpath (0, 1/3) of a; 
drawarrow subpath (1/3, 5/3) of a;
draw subpath (5/3, 2) of a;

drawarrow t;
drawarrow origin -- xm;
drawarrow origin -- xz;
draw origin withpen pencircle scaled dotlabeldiam;

% add the labels

label.ulft("$\vec{t}_0$", point 1/2 of t);
label.rt  ("$\vec{x}_0$", 3/4 xz);
label.lrt ("$\vec{x}_M$", 3/4 xm);
label.urt ("$\rho$", 1/2[xm, xz]);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}

you can compile this with lualatex to get a PDF that looks like this:

If you prefer the barbed arrows provided as "Stealth" in TikZ, then add these two lines, just after the ahangle line:
input mparrows
setarrows(barbed);

and recompile to get this version:

