Unable to shorten TikZ edge (bug?)
I'm unable to shorten the left side of the orange edge.

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style={
    draw, circle, line width=3pt,
    outer sep=0pt, inner sep=1pt,
  },
]

  \def\drawNodes{
    \node (A) at (0,-\n*.25) {};
    \node (B) at (1,-\n*.25) {};
  }

  \def\n{0}\drawNodes
  \draw [yellow] (A) edge (B);

  \def\n{1}\drawNodes
  \draw [red] (A) edge [shorten >=1.5pt] (B);

  \def\n{2}\drawNodes
  \draw [cyan] (A) edge [shorten <=1.5pt] (B);

  \def\n{3}\drawNodes
  \draw [green] (A) edge [->] ($(A)!.5!(B)$) edge (B);

  \def\n{4}\drawNodes
  \draw [magenta] (A) edge [->] ($(A)!.5!(B)$) edge [shorten >=1.5pt] (B);

  \def\n{5}\drawNodes
  \draw [orange] (A) edge [->, shorten <=1.5pt] ($(A)!.5!(B)$) edge (B);
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Just curious, is the point of this to place an arrow at the midpoint of a line, or is there another reason why you want to break the path partway through?

Yes, I'm connecting many (input) units on the left with a single (hidden) unit on the right. Therefore, all arrows overlap and look rather messy. What looks reasonable is to shift the heads back on the connection, say midway. Moreover, the outer sep is set to 0 pt because otherwise nodes' relative placement will depend on the edge thickness. (outer sep is usually set to half the edge thickness such that "shortening" is automatically handled.)

Then you might find this question and its answers useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3161/86

I saw that, but the \arrow{} was undefined for me. Also, the final result is here.

Never mind, I tried to compile the minimal example and it's working on its own. I need to check why it's incompatible with my book's preamble.

Change the last \draw to
\draw [orange] (A) edge [->, shorten <=1.5pt] ($(A)!.5!(B)$) edge [blue] (B);

to see what is happening.

The edge from (A) to the midway point is shortened, but the one from (A) to (B) is not. If they are drawn in the same colour, this is less obvious. By drawing the second part in blue, it is clear this is what is happening.
edge constructs a separate path and then returns to its starting point. So (A) edge (B) edge (C) constructs two paths from (A), unlike (A) -- (B) -- (C) which constructs only one. In the former case, we get (A) -> (B) (A) -> (C), whereas in the latter, we get (A) -> (B) -> (C).
Options given on the main path apply to all edges by default. Hence, you could write
\draw [orange, shorten <=1.5pt] (A) edge [->] ($(A)!.5!(B)$) edge [blue] (B);

In this case, both edges will be orange and have shorten <=1.5pt. The first will get an arrow, ->, and the second will get blue. So you will get a line shortened on the left with an orange arrow in the middle, where the first half is blue (orange below) and the second blue (nothing below).

Aaaaah… I totally see that. Thanks! Is there a single liner for having the arrow midway and shorten left side beside adding shorten <=1.5pt to both edges or having two drawing commands? I'm just curious. It's not the end of the world if that's not possible. :)

@Atcold you could use a mark or change the position of the arrow tip?

@Atcold but you could just say \draw ([xshift=1.5pt]A) ... if you know the direction, as in this case. (might not work in your real scenario, of course.)

@Atcold or \draw [shorten <=1.5pt] (A) edge ... should work as the options for the path will apply to edges unless overridden. (untested)

AMAZING! The last comment is what I was looking for. Do you mind adding it to your main reply? This is exactly the solution to my question. Thanks a bunch!

@Atcold done :-).

Thanks! Final result.
